# Google App maker User picker

Tags: google-app-maker

App maker user picker field takes only one value. We want to add multiple names in the picker field. Do we need to configure in the picker field itself or do we need to write custom JavaScript code to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the User Picker widget in App Maker, you can only select one user at a time. You will need to use custom JavaScript in order to do multiple selections. You can find a great integration on how to easily select multiple users in the Training Hub template available here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/training-hub/

If you open the above template and if you go to the "AssignCourses" page you will see a possible integration on how you can make multiple user selections. Note that you still need to add user by user to a Grid which will contain all the users that you selected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks wilmar, will try this